# Strtok Problems C (EOF characters?)

Tags: c, string, text, eof, strtok

the code that i am trying to write is supposed to read text from a txt file and separate into strings. I have come to the following code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(){
    FILE *fp;
    int i=0;
    char *words=NULL,*word=NULL,c;
    if ((fp=fopen("monologue.txt","r"))==NULL){ /*Where monologue txt is a normal file with plain text*/
        printf("Error Opening File\n");
        exit(1);}
    while ((c = fgetc(fp))!= EOF){
        if (c=='\n'){ c = ' '; }
        words = (char *)realloc(words, ++i*sizeof(char));
        words[i-1]=c;}
    word=strtok(words," ");
    while(word!= NULL){
        printf("%s\n",word);
        word = strtok(NULL," ");}
    exit(0);
}
```

The problem is that the output that i get is not only the text (now as separate strings) but also some characters that are \r(which is carriage return) but also \241\r\002 that i cant find out what they are? Can you help me out?

Comment: is your file saved as unicode?

Comment: You call `realloc()` for each input character, increasing the size of the buffer by just 1 byte.  That's likely to be very inefficient.  Doubling the buffer size as needed will be faster.  And you need to check whether `realloc()` succeeded or failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is that you never place a null terminator at the end of the string you build up.

Change:

```
    while ((c = fgetc(fp))!= EOF){
        if (c=='\n'){ c = ' '; }
        words = (char *)realloc(words, ++i*sizeof(char));
        words[i-1]=c;}
    word=strtok(words," ");
```

To:

```
    while ((c = fgetc(fp))!= EOF){
        if (c=='\n'){ c = ' '; }
        ++i;
        words = (char *)realloc(words, i + 1);
        words[i-1]=c;}
    words[i] = '\0';
    word=strtok(words," ");
```

Comment: That works perfectly now but i cant understand on my code why the
    word = strtok(NULL," ");
is needed for the words to print correctly and furthermore how can i access each word in the word pointer if i want to use only one?

Comment: @Konstantinos: The `strtok(NULL," ")` is needed to get the next token - that's just the way that `strtok()` is designed to work.  I'm not sure what the second question in your comment means.